# Issue while SSHing DigitalOcean Droplet

Tags: ssh, digital-ocean

I am facing a problem while trying to SSH a DO droplet. It is running 4 Python scripts fetching data via API and storing in MySQL(running on same Droplet). It had no issue when I was running 2 Python script but I started facing issue of SSH when I ran 4. Intially it gave the error:

```
'shell request failed on channel 0
```

and I was unable to login. When I enabled the verbose mode after sending `-v` switch it took a while and then logged in with the following info:

```
OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 47: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 291.234.230.166 [291.234.230.166] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file dokey type 0
debug1: identity file dokey-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_9.0p1 Ubuntu-1ubuntu7
debug1: match: OpenSSH_9.0p1 Ubuntu-1ubuntu7 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 291.234.230.166:22 as 'root'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:lznBqzR8ZwxO68S3OLtGe9CaVe/RwXDyhlHpYRL31ro
debug1: Host '291.234.230.166' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/x/.ssh/known_hosts:125
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: dokey RSA SHA256:xKO5RRccCVxxx+iIlF6lnN0 explicit
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,webauthn-sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: publickey-hostbound@openssh.com (unrecognised)
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: dokey RSA SHA256:xKO5RRccCVxxx+iIlF6lnN0 explicit
debug1: Server accepts key: dokey RSA SHA256:xKO5RRccCVxxx+iIlF6lnN0 explicit
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to 291.234.230.166 ([291.234.230.166]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: Remote: /root/.ssh/authorized_keys:1: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
debug1: Remote: /root/.ssh/authorized_keys:1: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_ALL = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_CTYPE = UTF-8
Welcome to Ubuntu 22.10 (GNU/Linux 5.19.0-28-generic x86_64)
```

I am unable to understand why is it happening

Comment: This doesn't look like an ssh problem -- that `Welcome to Ubuntu 22.10` at the end means that you were able to log in successfully.

Comment: @larsks then what could it be? right now i am unable to login. Which logs should I check? To clarify, the server is up, everything is running

Comment: Can you log in on the console instead of using ssh?

Comment: @larsks No. It shows black screen after the *Connected* message.

Comment: @larsks can you pls help? I also have downloaded `syslogs` but getting now idea what to check there.

Comment: If you are unable to log in via ssh and you are unable to log in on the console you don't seem to have any method of ingress that would permit you to perform further diagnostics. Have you tried simply rebooting the host?

Comment: @larsks Yes I always reboot but donot know what to check now. BTW, I had 4 `screen` sessions active running Python script 24x7